# How to make my collapsible open by default

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'd like the collapsible content to be open by default, but not sure how to achieve this. Can anyone help, please?

I admit I have no idea what I'm doing, so hopefully, it's something very simple.

I think my question is pretty straightforward but I need to add more details to ask so this is just some random filler text.

Here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.collapsible3 {
  background-color: #FF5757;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 50%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.active, .collapsible3:hover {
  background-color: #FF6868;
}

.collapsible3:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content3 {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>

<button class="collapsible3">Button</button>
<div class="content3">
    <p> </p>
    <p style="font-size: 16px; text-indent: 20px;">Content</p>
</div>

<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible3");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes in the **if condition** in the script tag

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button class="accordion" ng-click="">
        <b>SEARCH BY MONTH</b></button>
    <div class="panel" style="background-color: red; height: 150px">
        <!--<p>
                                <label for="amount">Month range:</label>
                            </p>-->
        <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;
            width: 100%">
       
        <br />
        <!--Start DateTime : <span id="lblStartDateTime"></span><br />
                            End DateTime : <span id="lblEndDateTime"></span>-->
    </div>
    <hr />
  
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click",function () {
        /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
        to highlight the button that controls the panel */
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
        var panel1 =this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel1.style.display ==="block") {
            panel1.style.display ="none";
        }else {
            panel1.style.display ="block";
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the working [demo](https://jsbin.com/vatixisoyi/1/edit?html,js,output)